# mySQL combining data from tables query

Tags: php, mysql

Just doing some mySQL problems and have figured out all but the very last one (of course).

I have two tables.

The Question asked is "Write a query to return a list of all authors who live in the same city as any
publisher."

Apologies as I'm not allowed to post images. But It's easy to figure out the headings to it's value nevertheless. I've added commas into the first few to separate them so you know the general workings.

**Publishers table**

```
PUB_ID PUB_NAME CITY STATE COUNTRY
0736 New Moon, Palo Alto, CA, USA
0877 Binnet & Hardley, Washington, DC, USA
1389 Algodata, Berkeley, CA, USA
1622 Five Lakes, Chicago, IL, USA
1756 Ramona Publishers Oakland CA USA
9901 GGG&G Munich NULL NULL
9952 Scootney Books New York NY USA
9999 Lucerne Publishing Paris NULL France
```

**Authors table**

```
AU_ID LNAME FNAME PHONE ADDRESS CITY STATE CONTRACT
172 White Johnson, 496-7223, 10932 Bigge Rd Menlo Park, CA 1
213 Green Marjorie, 986-7020, 309 63rd St. Oakland, CA 2
238 Carson Cheryl, 548-7723, 589 Darwin Ln, Berkeley, CA 1
267 O‟Leary Michael 286-2428 22 Cleveland Av San Jose CA 1
274 Straight Dean 834-2919 5420 College Av Oakland CA 2
```

I understand I have to use an Inner Join statement but how to do that AND match up the authors that live in the same city as a publisher is what is confusing me.

Comment: Don't apologize, posting images is bad, text is good. We can't cut and paste images into a table.

Comment: Why isn't there a `COUNTRY` column in `Authors`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Authors AS a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT city, state
      FROM Publishers) AS p
ON a.city = p.city AND a.state = p.state
```

`DISTINCT` prevents it from producing multiple results for an author if there's more than one publisher in their city.

You can also do it with a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM Authors AS a
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT *
              FROM Publishers AS p
              WHERE p.city = a.city AND p.state = a.state)
```

Comment: Join+select+distinct? Isn't it group by?

Comment: They're equivalent if you're only returning the columns that you're grouping by. `GROUP BY` should be used when you're also returning other columns or using aggregate functions.

Comment: Where have you got "a.*" from? Are you using it as a variable to select all data in the city column? Likewise with "p". I'm just learning mySQL so I'm coming from a beginner level so apologies if it's a stupid question, but It's gotta be done to learn I guess. It works though, thank you.

Comment: It comes from the `AS a` alias, it's a short name for `Authors.`.

Comment: @Barmar, I know what GROUP BY does,  you can perform this task without using subqueries

Comment: Yes, but then the intermediate table from the `JOIN` will be larger, because it will contain multiple rows from all the matching publishers in the same city. It's more efficient to reduce the table before the join.